# Why won't this HLSL Pixel Shader compile when RWStructuredBuffer is referenced?

Tags: directx, shader, hlsl, pixel-shader, directx-12

I'm using DirectX 12, trying to render using UAVs. Here is my pixel shader code:

```
    struct PSInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

struct FragmentDataStruct
{
    float4 color;
    float depth;
};

struct FragmentAndLinkStruct
{
    FragmentDataStruct fragmentData;
    uint nextFragment;
};

RWStructuredBuffer <FragmentAndLinkStruct> FLBuffer : register(u0);

RWByteAddressBuffer StartOffsetBuffer : register(u1);

float4 PSMain(PSInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    input.color.x = float(FLBuffer[0].nextFragment);

    return input.color;
}
```

It fails compilation when using the `D3DCompileFromFile` function.

When I replace this line:

```
input.color.x = float(FLBuffer[0].nextFragment);
```

with something like this:

```
FragmentAndLinkStruct otherThing;
otherThing.nextFragment = 1;
input.color.x = float(otherThing.nextFragment);
```

that has no mention of the `RWStructuredBuffer`, then it compiles just fine and renders properly.

I don't think I have any issues with bound data (VS Graphics Debugger shows the two UAVs bound properly). I don't think that would affect the compiling of the shader, though.

Any time I reference `FLBuffer` or `StartOffsetBuffer`, it won't compile.

What would cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem after figuring out how to read the error given by the compiler. The issue here was that the render target output uses the `u0` shader register.

To find this, I read out the error given natively from `D3DCompileFromFile` as an `ID3DBlob*` by converting it to a `char*` array using the code below, where `error` is an `ID3DBlob*`:

```
const char* error2 = static_cast<const char*>(error->GetBufferPointer());
```

I set a breakpoint immediately after the last line and simply read out the error message from the locals tab in VS:

```
error X4509: UAV registers live in the same name space as outputs, so they
must be bound to at least u1, manual bind to slot u0 failed
```

The error message is VERY clear and concise. Very helpful.

The updated code:

```
struct PSInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

struct FragmentDataStruct
{
    float4 color;
    float depth;
};

struct FragmentAndLinkStruct
{
    FragmentDataStruct fragmentData;
    uint nextFragment;
};

RWStructuredBuffer <FragmentAndLinkStruct> FLBuffer : register(u1);

RWByteAddressBuffer StartOffsetBuffer : register(u2);

float4 PSMain(PSInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    uint pixelCount = FLBuffer.IncrementCounter();
    input.color.x = float(pixelCount);

    return input.color;
}
```

As a note, the compiler won't even look at code that doesn't contribute to the `return` output. I tested this by adding some code to the `PSMain` function that interacted with the `FLBuffer` without affecting `input.color`, which is returned. Looking at the disassembly, all the superfluous code was removed and not compiled.

Separately, since I didn't reference `FLBuffer` when it worked, it didn't make any connection between the output shader register and the `u0` shader register I bound, so no issue arose.

I then have to assume that it gets rid of superfluous code before sanity checking that code, which makes sense when looking for efficiency. Once it does a sanity check, then it proceeds to compile.

Hopefully this helps someone learning DirectX or HLSL later.